# Замена контейнера из панели навигации через ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

На главной странице есть множество контейнеров навигация по которым происходит через плавный скролл и имеется панель html панель навигации:

```
   <ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#general">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="news.php">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Контакт</a></li>
</ul>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Новости" у меня заменялся контейнер ajax'ом, для этого укралсворовалпохитил данный js код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        link=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
        })
        .done(function(html){
            $("#body-container").empty().append(html)
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function(){
            console.log("complete");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Но он никак не отзывается, в этой теме совсем новичок, заранее спасибо.

Полный код страницы:

```
<? include_once 'main.php';
include_once 'newsquery.php';

echo <<<_END

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js oldie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js oldie ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

   <!--- basic page needs
   ================================================== -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Тестовый сайт</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

   <!-- mobile specific metas
   ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS
   ================================================== -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

   <!-- script
   ================================================== -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

   <!-- favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" >

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
        });
      };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- header
   ================================================== -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <header id="main-header">

    <div class="row">

          <div class="logo">
             <a href="index.php">Тест</a>
          </div>

          <nav id="nav-wrap">

             <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">
                <span class="menu-icon">Меню</span>
             </a>
            <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">
                <span class="menu-icon">Меню</span>
            </a>

             <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="index.php">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="news.php">Новости</a></li>
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">О нас</a></li>
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Контакт</a></li>
             </ul> <!-- end #nav -->

          </nav> <!-- end #nav-wrap -->

          <ul class="header-social">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
          </ul>

       </div>

   </header> <!-- end header -->


   <!-- homepage hero
   ================================================== -->

 <section id="hero">

 <div id="body-container"> 

        <div class="row hero-content">

            <div class="twelve columns hero-container">

               <!-- hero-slider start-->
               <div id="hero-slider" class="flexslider">

                   <ul class="slides">

                       <!-- slide -->
                       <li>
                           <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h1 class="">$news1
                                </h1>

                                <h3 class="">$description11</h3>
                                <br> <class="">$newsdate1

                            </div>
                       </li>

                       <!-- slide -->
                       <li>
                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h1 class="">$news2</h1>

                                <h3 class="">$description22</h3>
                                <br> <class="">$newsdate2

                            </div>
                       </li>

                   </ul>

               </div> <!-- end hero-slider -->

          </div> <!-- end twelve columns-->

        </div> <!-- end row -->



   </section> <!-- end homepage hero -->


   <!-- portfolio
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="portfolio">

      <div class="row section-head">

        <div class="twelve columns">

            <h1>Our Latest Projects<span>.</span></h1>

             <hr />

             <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.
             </p>

          </div>

      </div> <!-- end section-head -->

      </div>  <!-- end row -->

   </section> <!-- end portfolio -->

   <!-- contact
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="contact">

    <div class="row section-head">

        <div class="twelve columns">

             <h1>Обратная связь<span>.</span></h1>

             <hr />         

          </div>

      </div> <!-- end section-head -->

      <div class="row">

        <div id="contact-form" class="six columns tab-whole left">

            <!-- form -->
            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="mail.php"  >
                <fieldset>

                  <div class="group">
                           <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Имя" value="" minLength="2" required />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                       <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Эл. адрес" value="" required />
                   </div>

                  <div>
                        <textarea name="message"  id="message" placeholder="Сообщение" rows="10" cols="50" required ></textarea>
                   </div>

                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LepbOEUAAAAAIpvYsm-KELj1CksBS8YD1d7bsL5"></div><br>

                  <div>
                     <button name="enter" class="submitform">Отправить</button>
                     <div id="submit-loader">
                        <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>                             
                          <div class="s-loader">
                                    <div class="bounce1"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce2"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce3"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                  </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form> <!-- Form End -->

            <!-- contact-warning -->
            <div id="message-warning"></div>
            <!-- contact-success -->
            <div id="message-success">
               <i class="icon-ok"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br />
            </div>

         </div>


      </div> <!-- end row -->     

   </section>  <!-- end contact -->

</div>

   <!-- Footer
   ================================================== -->
   <footer>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="twelve columns content group">

                <ul class="social-links">
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vimeo-square"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

            <hr />

            <div class="info">

                <div class="footer-logo"></div>

                <p>Футер тестового сайта.
                </p>

             </div>

        </div>

         <ul class="copyright">
            <li>Какой то текст.</li>
         </ul>

        <!-- <div id="go-top">
            <a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#hero">Вверх<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
         </div>-->

      </div> <!-- end row -->

   </footer> <!-- end footer -->

 <!--  <div id="preloader">
        <div id="loader"></div>
   </div> -->

   <!-- Java Script
   ================================================== -->
   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   <script src="news2.js"></script>
   <script src="mail.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>


</body>

</html>
_END;
?>
```

Comment: @Leonid "Остаётся вопрос: куда сделает запрос метод для якоря?" - если честно не особо понял формулировку. "Для news.php отдельный вопрос? Что мы получим по этому адресу?" - полную замену контейнера body-container (в теории).

Comment: @Leonid ссылка на новости при наведении на кнопку в панели навигации выглядит как и задумано.

Comment: @Leonid даже без этого ссылка была читаема, т.к. файл находился в корне. Прописал как вы посоветовали, ничего не поменялось. 0 реакции на вкладке новости, а при использовании остальных начинает вечно крутиться прелоадер.

Comment: @Leonid Из ошибок только это, но к этому делу не относится.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:184)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)

Comment: @Leonid нет, вообще нет никакой реакции, я об этом сразу написал.

Comment: @Leonid конечно.

Comment: @Leonid С таким кодом всплывает сначала комплит, потом клик. Но все это получается пустить только если свернуть окно и оно адаптируется под мобильную версию с выдвижным меню, хотя выхлопа по итогу все равно нет.

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 console.log('click')
 $("a").click(function(event){
  console.log('event')
  link=$(this).attr("href");
  $.ajax({
   url: link,
  })
  .done(function(html){
   $("#body-container").empty().append(html)
  })
  .fail(function(){
   console.log("error");
  })
.always(function(){
console.log("complete");
});
return false;
});
});

Comment: @Leonid да, из always. В функцию хтмл сразу попытался пихнуть, но функция сыпется и тогда просто заменяется все на файл news.php, а не контейнер.

Comment: @Leonid про точку с запятой в прошлый раз забыл, сделал. В консоли выводятся click> event> html> complete.

Comment: Добрый вечер, подскажите, что конкретно Вам необходимо? Чтобы по нажатии на новости делался запрос через `ajax` куда? Что должно вернуться?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Добрый, да, чтобы при нажатии на "Новости" заменялось содержимое контейнера "body-container" на содержимое файла news.php.

Comment: Только `news` или остальные тоже? А что Вы хотите выполнить именно `ajax` запросом? Можно при нажатии на картинку просто подгрузить ссылку.

Comment: @Denis640Kb на примере news я сделаю уже остальные кнопки. Ajaxом хочу заменить контейнер не перезагружая страницы, простой переход по ссылке мне не нужен. Грубо говоря я хочу использовать макет с панелью навигации и футером и заменять остальной контент в середине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нет необходимости использовать `ajax` в данном случае. 
Вот пример подгрузки данных - добавил комментариев для понимания кода:

```js
    window.onload = function () { // При загрузке страницы
        let parent = document.getElementById('nav'); //Ищем элемент по id nav (Навигационная панель)
        let a = parent.getElementsByTagName('a'); // Из этого элемента ищем элементы с тегом а. (Ищем именно в parent, чтобы не попали туда другие ссылки)

        for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){ // Перебираем все элементы
            a[i].addEventListener('click', function () { // При нажатии на кнопку
                event.preventDefault(); // Убираем стандартное действие (Переход по ссылке)
                let href = a[i].href; // Получаем аттрибут href элемента
                $("#body-container").empty().load(href); // Очищаем элемент и подгружаем нужный файл.
            })
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#general">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="news.php">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Контакт</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="body-container">Начальные данные</div>
```

Второй файл `php`, с названием `news.php` (Лежит в этой же директории):

```php
<?php
?>

<style>
    .text{
        background-color: #003eff;
    }
</style>
<div class="text">Данные из news</div>
```

При данной реализации у Вас будут подгружаться файлы, указанные в `href` каждой ссылки в контейнер без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Да, подгрузка работает, но отгружает только первый встречный контейнер, все что за ним игнорирует.

Comment: @MrYogurt Что значит подгружает первый встречный контейнер?

Comment: Отгружает, а не подгружает. Т.е. отгрузился один информационный контейнер, а остальные остались, хотя я обернул контейнером "body-container" гораздо больше.

Comment: @MrYogurt Ещё раз. При нажатии на кнопку - у Вас в контейнер с `id` `body-container` загружается html документ из другого файла. Про какие другие Вы говорите?

Comment: $("#body-container").empty() - здесь как я понимаю должно полностью очиститься содержимое боди контейнера и на его место встать news.php, но у меня отгрузился только первый контейнер внутри боди контейнера и на его место встал news.php.

Comment: @MrYogurt Ну так же и должно быть. Или у Вас несколько контейнеров с `id` `body-container`? Чтобы сказать детальнее, что конкретно теперь у Вас добавьте тогда Вашу разметку `html` в вопрос или выложите на `codepen`.

Comment: Добавил полный код.

Comment: @MrYogurt У Вас не полностью обёрнуты данные в `div` с `id` `body-container`. 
Вам надо его перенести перед `section` и закрытие тега сделать перед `footer

Comment: Сделал, уже теплее, удалилось все, кроме формы обратной связи.

Comment: @MrYogurt  У Вас там `div` `body-container` закрывается раньше, чем начинается форма. Перенесите один `</div>` в конец. То, что я писал в сообщении выше.

Comment: Да, супер глупая ошибка была, огромное вам спасибо за терпение и запредельно развернутые ответы.

Comment: @MrYogurt  Не за что ) Удачной Вам работы.

Comment: Еще раз здравствуйте, снова нужна ваша помощь, а чат не доступен с моим рейтингом. По итогу оказалось, что ваш скрипт мне не совсем подходит, т.к. при переходе снова на главную не прогружаются некоторые контейнеры и я решил накидать прицельный скрипт, который будет работать с конкретной ссылкой, но не могу этот код даже протестировать (ругается на скобку после функции), уже часа 3 на него залипаю впустую, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой. Допускаю, что скрипт полностью неправильный, но в js я около ноль.

Comment: window.onload = function () {
for (let news of document.body.children) {
if (elem.matches('a[href$="news.php"]')) {
for (news.addEventListener('click', function () {
event.preventDefault();
let href = news.href;
$("#body-container").empty().load(href);
})
}
}
}

Comment: @MrYogurt Что значит `при переходе снова на главную не прогружаются некоторые контейнеры `? Вы спросили, как подгрузить другой файл, при нажатии на кнопку. Попробуйте написать ещё один вопрос, постарайтесь его максимально сформулировать и отправьте ссылку мне.

Comment: @MrYogurt Если теоретически, то лишний `for`    `function () {
        for (let news of document.body.children) {
            if (elem.matches('a[href$="news.php"]')) {
                news.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    let href = news.href;
                    $("#body-container").empty().load(href);
                });
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098133/Замена-контента-из-ссылки-в-панели-навигации