# Замена контента из ссылки в панели навигации

Tags: javascript

Есть панель навигации:

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
  <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="general.php">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="news.php">Новости</a></li>
  <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">О нас</a></li>
  <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Контакт</a></li>
</ul>
```

Есть js скрипт, который заменяет контент в области контейнера body-container при нажатии на ссылку:

```
window.onload = function () {
    let parent = document.getElementById('nav');
    let a = parent.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        a[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = a[i].href;
            $("#body-container").empty().load(href);
        })
    }
}
```

Замена контента из news.php проходит нормально, но когда я пытаюсь заменить на недостающую часть от index.php, которая находится в general.php перестает нормально работать часть блоков, что исправить у меня не получилось и слишком трудозатратно. Для себя вижу выход в прицельной обработке ссылок из js скрипта по типу такого кода:

```
 window.onload = function () {
     for (let news of document.body.children) {
        if (news.matches('a[href$="news.php"]')) {
            news.addEventListener('click', function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                let href = news.href;
                $("#body-container").empty().load(href);
            });
        } 
     } 
 }
```

Но из за недостатка опыта не могу его даже протестировать, ругается на неожиданную открытую скобку после первой функции. Нужна помощь в исправлении или в совете по способу реализации.

Upd. Обновил нижний js код, исправил ошибку, теперь он просто не работает.

Comment: for (news.addEventListener('click', function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = news.href;
            $("#body-container").empty().load(href);
    }) что это?

Comment: @Leonid вопрос конечно хороший, но если бы я знал, то сюда не писал.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что такое "недостающую часть от index.php"?

Comment: @Igor в общем при открытии сайта, на главной (index.php) есть шапка сайта с меню навигации и футер, между ними еще куча контейнеров, которые обернуты в "body-container" и должны заменяться по ссылке. При замене на news.php все проходит нормально, а при замене на general.php (где вырезаемые контейнеры из index.php) контейнеры не раздупляются как надо.

Comment: Стало еще хуже :(.

Comment: @MrYogurt Только сейчас заметил ссылку. Указывайте, пожалуйста, через @ )  У Вас есть 3 файла - index.php`, `general.php` и `main.php`. При нажатии на кнопку в первом скрипте у Вас берётся название файла из `href` этой ссылки и загружается этот контент в блок с `id` - `body-container`. Что дальше Вы хотите сделать? Не совсем понятно. При нажатии на кнопку `general` у Вас и так загрузятся данные из файла `general.php` в тот же блок с `id` `body-container`. Про какие дополнительные элементы идёт речь?

Comment: @Denis640Kb под прошлым вопросом я писал под вашим ответом, вам должно было автоматически отправляться уведомление и призыв вообще не работал. Про элементы лучше забудьте, там просто проблема с подгрузкой скриптов как я понял, решать конкретно ее не хочется, хочется больше понимать js. Давайте обсуждать мою попытку написать новый скрипт, который должен работать только с конкретной ссылкой при нахождении совпадений, но выполнять ту же функцию, что описывал еще в прошлом вопросе.

Comment: @MrYogurt Что-то не видел сообщения. Ну да ладно. Добавил несколько исправлений как лучше это обработать. Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на комментарии. Постарался подробнее расписать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постарался добавить больше комментариев для понимания.

Вы пробовали получить элементы через `document.body.children`, что возвращало Вам один элемент `ul`, так как в боди один `child` этот элемент. 
А уже в этом элементе другие элементы. 
В каждом элементе `ul` есть `child` элемент `li`, а в каждом элементе `li` есть `chiled` элемент `a`. 
По этому Вы не могли получить `href` этой ссылки. 
Что касается `news.matches('a[href$="news.php"]')` , то в этом случае Вы пытались найти подобный элемент, в `ul`, и соответсвенно его не было. 
Если Вы хотите добавить подобную проверку, у Вас будет подгружаться контент только по нажатии на кнопку `main.php` игнорируя другие. 
Если Вы хотите подгружать контент каждой ссылки, то лучше использовать так:

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        let ul = document.getElementById('nav').children; // Получаем элементы не всего body (Так как в такой выборке будет только один элемент ul) в сразу получаем все child этого ul по id
        for (let news of ul) { // Для каждого элемента li ( Так как в ul у нас элементы li, а уже в них <a>
            let a = news.children[0]; // Получаем его child - элемент <a>( Который вложен в каждый li )
            a.addEventListener('click', function () { // Слушаем событие нажатия кнопки
                event.preventDefault(); // Убираем стандартный переход по ссылке.
                let href = a.href; // Получаем ссылку элемента
                console.log(href);
                let fileName = href.split('/').pop(); // Так как ссылка в файле указывается относительно проекта, тоесть https://localhost:32432/... и так далее, то разделяем ссылку по / и получаем последний элемент.
                $("#body-container").empty().load(fileName); // Очищаем элемент и загружаем туда ссылку.
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="general.php">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="loadFile.php">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Контакт</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="body-container"></div>
```

Для выборки только одного элемента:

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        $("a[href^='main.php']").on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Убираем стандартный переход по ссылке.
            let z = $("a[href^='main.php']").attr('href');
            $("#body-container").empty().load(z); // Очищаем элемент и загружаем туда ссылку.
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="general.php">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="main.php">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Контакт</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="body-container"></div>
```

Comment: Вы не поняли моей хотелки, я хотел сделать условие, которое будет проверять элемент на наличие конкретной ссылки, к примеру news.php, если в одном из элементов находится такая ссылка, то должен сработать скрипт замены, если такой ссылки нет, скрипт самоубивается.

Comment: @MrYogurt Так у Вас изначально же код совершенно не правильный был.

Comment: Собственно я обратного и не утверждал, говорил же, совсем новичок.

Comment: @MrYogurt Добавил только для одного элемента

Comment: Отлично, все работает идеально, огромное спасибо х2.

Comment: @MrYogurt Рад помочь ))) Я думал, что надо каждую выбранную ссылку подгружать, оказалось, что только одну )

Comment: На самом деле в идеале можно и каждую, но как я уже сказал, столкнулся с непонятками в подгрузке элементов обратно, когда они в коде отображаются как надо, а на странице их не видно, насколько я понял это проблема с недогрузом скриптов, но разбираться с этого ракурса было лень, решил пытаться делать прицельный скрипт, но попал в еще больший просак.